# SQL While Loop returning only first result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have some trouble with a while loop - ideally I would grab dates less than to the end of the year but have settled for dates 52 weeks from now (less than 53 MAX)

For some reason the Loop using @Freqcounter isn't working - I return only 0's.
The SQL is valid but only produces the first value of 0 for the @Freqcounter - no iterations.
Any ideas why it won't iterate?

```
DECLARE @Freqcounter INT

SET @Freqcounter = 0

While @Freqcounter < 53
Begin
    (Select distinct
    Asset.AssetNumber,
    CustomFields_Asset.HA_Identifier,
    PreventativeMaintenance.PreventativeMaintenanceNumber,
    PreventativeMaintenance.PreventativeMaintenanceDescription,
    PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime,
    Region.RegionName,
    Case 
    When vwAssets7Levels.EquipParent2 is NULL Then Asset.AssetNumber
    Else vwAssets7Levels.EquipParent2 
    End as Site,
    @Freqcounter as [FreqCounter],
    PRINT @Freqcounter,
    CASE
        when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Years' then
        DATEADD(year, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + @Freqcounter, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
        when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Months' then
        DATEADD(month, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + @Freqcounter, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
        when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Weeks' then
        DATEADD(Week, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + @Freqcounter, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
    End as [Next Due Date]

From    
    PreventativeMaintenanceAsset
    Left Join PreventativeMaintenance on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.PreventativeMaintenanceID = PreventativeMaintenance.PreventativeMaintenanceID
    Left Join Asset on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.AssetID = Asset.AssetID
    Left join vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.PreventativeMaintenanceID =     vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.PreventativeMaintenanceID
    Left join vwAssets7Levels On PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.AssetID = vwAssets7Levels.AssetID
    Left Join CustomFields_Asset On vwAssets7Levels.IDEquiparent3 = CustomFields_Asset.AssetID
    Left Join RegionAsset On PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.AssetID = RegionAsset.AssetID
    Left Join Region On Region.RegionID = RegionAsset.RegionID

Where
    (Region.RegionName IN ('Central', 'Eastern', 'Western', NULL) or Region.RegionName = NULL)
    And PreventativeMaintenance.IsActive = 'True'
    And PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.IsInUse = 'True')

SET @Freqcounter = @Freqcounter + 1;

End;
```

as per nbk's comments - dropped the while loop.
Trying to build a schedule that projects a year+ forward. The time increments can be weeks, months or years. to get around this I have created a sub table 'Forward' with 52 weeks.

Now I need to pull the Forward.Level (1-52) and add to the PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency

Final solution is working perfeclt - use two CTE's rather than a while loop.
Also noted a few other suggestions which I will implement too. Thanks for everyones help so far.

```
WITH Forward (level) as
(
   SELECT 1 as level
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  level + 1
   FROM Forward
   WHERE level < 53
),

ForwardPMA (PreventativeMaintenanceAssetID, level) as
(
   SELECT PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.PreventativeMaintenanceAssetID, level
   From PreventativeMaintenanceAsset
   Cross Join Forward
)

Select distinct 
Asset.AssetNumber,
CustomFields_Asset.HA_Identifier,
PreventativeMaintenance.PreventativeMaintenanceNumber,
PreventativeMaintenance.PreventativeMaintenanceDescription,
PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime,
Region.RegionName,
Case 
When vwAssets7Levels.EquipParent2 is NULL Then Asset.AssetNumber
Else vwAssets7Levels.EquipParent2 
End as Site,
CASE
when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Years' then
DATEADD(year, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + ForwardPMA.level, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Months' then
DATEADD(month, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + ForwardPMA.level, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Weeks' then
DATEADD(Week, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + ForwardPMA.level, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
End as [Next Due Date]

From 
PreventativeMaintenanceAsset
Left Join PreventativeMaintenance on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.PreventativeMaintenanceID = PreventativeMaintenance.PreventativeMaintenanceID
Left Join Asset on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.AssetID = Asset.AssetID
Left join vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.PreventativeMaintenanceID = vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.PreventativeMaintenanceID
Left join vwAssets7Levels On PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.AssetID = vwAssets7Levels.AssetID
Left Join CustomFields_Asset On vwAssets7Levels.IDEquiparent3 = CustomFields_Asset.AssetID
Left Join RegionAsset On PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.AssetID = RegionAsset.AssetID
Left Join Region On Region.RegionID = RegionAsset.RegionID
Left Join ForwardPMA on PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.PreventativeMaintenanceAssetID = ForwardPMA.PreventativeMaintenanceAssetID

Where
(Region.RegionName IN ('Central', 'Eastern', 'Western', NULL) or Region.RegionName = NULL)
And PreventativeMaintenance.IsActive = 'True'
And PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.IsInUse = 'True'
And 
CASE
when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Years' then
DATEADD(year, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + ForwardPMA.level, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Months' then
DATEADD(month, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + ForwardPMA.level, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
when vwPreventativeMaintenanceAssetListing.FrequencyTypeName = 'Weeks' then
DATEADD(Week, PreventativeMaintenance.Frequency + ForwardPMA.level, PreventativeMaintenanceAsset.LastDoneDateTime)
End < DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -0);
```

Comment: try to insert your select into a temporary table and after the loop selelct all rows from the temptaböe

Comment: Thanks nbk - still learning creating tables - will post my attempt

Comment: can you please provide a full [mre] see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  your loop is not right and the query probably doesn't need any loop in the first place only a group by, but test that a dbfiddle would also help

Comment: I think it needs a loop as I have to iterate over the frequency - basically the query has a last done date and then a next due.
But I want to grab the frequency (week, month or year) and add to the next due to project the schedule into the future.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you have same logic in where condition execute 53 times, the difference is only "Next Due Date" column...
P.S. as @nbk suggested , put select WITHOUT last column (case statement) in temp table or table variable.
than add case column in last while loop

Comment: in addition, as an option to replace case with EquipParent2 (would be cleaner): COALESCE(vwAssets7Levels.EquipParent2, Asset.AssetNumber) as Site, and avoid spaces in column names.

Comment: How come you have a `PRINT @Freqcounter` in the middle of your query ?

Comment: PowerMouse - have changed the query a little and amended my query by removing the while loop.
What I am trying to achieve is a foward schedule. Basically Last done Date + Week/Month/Year x interval to generate at least 1 year foward. 

Noted on the COALESCE - good pickup

Comment: FYI, but syntax like `ColumnName IN (NULL)` and `ColumnName = NULl` will *never* evaluate to TRUE. The only way to compare to a `NULL` is with `IS NULL`. Nothing is (not) equal to `NULL`, *including* `NULL`. Though here, is seem more like `Region.RegionName IN ('Central', 'Eastern', 'Western')` should be in your `ON`, not your `WHERE`.

Comment: what's the amount of rows for ```@Freqcounter = 0``` and how long does it take to finish this query?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to forward table this is return you list of dates.

```
DECLARE 
  @StartDateTime DATE = GetDate()-20
, @EndDateTime DATE = DateAdd(week, 52, GetDate())

;WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
)
SELECT DateData
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

so you can join on conditions to match date in future.

Comment: check this link good reading on weeknumber and range https://medium.com/@gembit.soultan/generate-1-year-calendar-based-on-52-weeks-in-sql-server-67148f45a5da